# How to set multiple 404 rewrite rule in .htaccess for multiple domain?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have 2 domain pointed in same document root directory.

```
www.one.com   --- Document root in /var/www/
www.two.com   --- Document root in /var/www/
```

I have 2 different html page for 404 for those 2 domain separately.

```
/var/www/one404.html
/var/www/two404.html
```

I want when any 404 redirection will happen in www.one.com then it will redirect to www.one.com/one404.html

Also the same way when any 404 redirection will happen in www.two.com then it will redirect to www.two.com/two404.html

Hope i can describe my query clearly.

I just want to know what is the rewrite condition I need to mention in my .htaccess for multiple domain?

Is there any PHP code which can do this alternatively??

Answer (score 0):

In the vhost config for each domain add:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /one404.html
```

or `two404.html` respectively. I don't think you can add it in the `.htaccess` without some switch on the host.

Redirecting on a `404` is not advised.